# Moving focussed sprites gradually to target position (C++ & SFML)

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to find out, how to move sprites to a target position. (focus a sprite by left-click and then left-click again to move it towards the position, that was clicked). What's wrong with my code? How to implement such functionality. Thx in advance for any help.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow mMainWindow(sf::VideoMode(600,600), "Map", sf::Style::Close);
    mMainWindow.setFramerateLimit(60);
    mMainWindow.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);
    sf::Image image;
    image.create(50, 50, sf::Color::Red);
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromImage(image);

    std::vector<sf::Sprite> EnemyVector;
    std::vector<sf::Vector2f> EnemyPositions;
    std::vector<sf::Vector2f> EnemyVelocities;

    sf::Sprite* focus = nullptr;
    bool move = false;

    while (mMainWindow.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        bool creating = false;
        bool leftclicked = false;

        sf::Vector2i mousePos;

        while (mMainWindow.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                mMainWindow.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                creating = (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A);
                break;
            case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                {
                    leftclicked = true;
                    mousePos = sf::Vector2i(event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (creating)
        {
            sf::Sprite sprite;
            mousePos = (mousePos == sf::Vector2i(0, 0) ? sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow) : mousePos);
            sprite.setTexture(texture);
            sprite.setColor(sf::Color::Red);
            sprite.setOrigin(static_cast<float>(sprite.getTextureRect().width) / 2, static_cast<float>(sprite.getTextureRect().height) / 2);
            sprite.setPosition(static_cast<float>(mousePos.x), static_cast<float>(mousePos.y));
            focus=nullptr;
            EnemyVector.push_back(sprite);
            EnemyPositions.push_back(sf::Vector2f(static_cast<float>(mousePos.x), static_cast<float>(mousePos.y)));
            EnemyVelocities.push_back(sf::Vector2f(0,0));
        }
        if (leftclicked)
        {
            for (auto& enemy = EnemyVector.rbegin(); enemy != EnemyVector.rend(); ++enemy)
            {
                if (enemy->getGlobalBounds().contains(static_cast<float>(mousePos.x), static_cast<float>(mousePos.y)))
                {
                    focus = &(*enemy);
                    move = !move;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(move)
        {
            if(focus!=nullptr)
            {
                focus->move((sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow).x*0.1 - focus->getPosition().x*0.1),(sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow).y*0.1 - focus->getPosition().y*0.1)) ;
            }
        }
        mMainWindow.clear();
        for (auto& enemy = EnemyVector.rbegin(); enemy != EnemyVector.rend(); ++enemy)
        {
            mMainWindow.draw(*enemy);
        }
        mMainWindow.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two ways:

1. Do it in the event loop
2. Use threads

For both you need to keep destination coordinates for the sprites.

Using the event-loop method you have to modify the event loop to not block waiting for events, and then update the sprites coordinates when needed and redraw.

If you use threads, one thread can update the coordinates of all sprites that should be moving, and ask the main rendering thread to redraw.

It should be noted that both methods are basically the same, the difference is only where the current position of the sprites are updated.